# Time for 2 nodes to collide

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, tree

We are given a graph of `N` nodes. `(1-N)`, where each node has exactly `1` directed edge to some node (this node can be the same node).

We need to answer the **queries** of type : `A, B`, which asks **time** required when 2 objects collide if one start at `A` and other start at `B`. Both moves `1` hop in `1` sec. If it's not possible for them to collide time would be `-1`.

Time : from `X` -> to `Y` : 1 hop = 1 second.

**Constraints** :

```
N, Q <= 10^5 (number of nodes, number of queries).
```

**Example** : for given graph

```
   A -> B -> C -> D -> E
                  ^    |
                  K <- F

Query(A, E) : 3 seconds, as at time t = 3 secs they both will be on node D.
Query(C, D) : -1 seconds, as they will never collide.
```

> What's the optimal way to answer each query?

Brute Force Approach: time - `O(Q * N)`

Improved solution using **binary lifting technique**: time - `O(Q * log(N))`

```
private static int[] collisionTime(int N, int Q, int[] A, int[][] queries) {

    // ancestor matrix : creation time- O(n * log(n))
    int M = (int) (Math.ceil(Math.log10(N) / Math.log10(2))) + 1;
    int[][] ancestor = new int[N + 1][M];
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        ancestor[i][0] = A[i]; // 2^0-th ancestor. 
    }
    for(int j = 1; j < M; j++) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            ancestor[i][j] = ancestor[ancestor[i][j-1]][j-1];
        }
    }

    int[] answer = new int[Q];
    for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++) { 
        int u = queries[i][0];
        int v = queries[i][1];
        answer[i] = timeToCollide(u, v, ancestor);
    }

    return answer;
}

// using binary lifting: time- O(log(n))
private static int timeToCollide(int u, int v, int[][] ancestor) {
    int m = ancestor[0].length;

    // edge cases
    if(u == v)                              // already in collision state
        return 0;              
    if(ancestor[u][m-1] != ancestor[v][m-1]) // their top most ancestor is not the same means they cannot collide at all.
        return -1;

    int t = 0;
    for(int j = m - 1; j >=0; j--) {
        if(ancestor[u][j] != ancestor[v][j]) {
            u = ancestor[u][j];
            v = ancestor[v][j];
            t += Math.pow(2, j);
        }
    }
    return t + 1;
}
```

Comment: From a graph, you might have the cycle and the "queue" sizes, so modulus can be used. no need of bruteforce.

Comment: I think that you can do it in `O(Q + N)`.  Not certain though...

Comment: Here is one approach that comes in my mind. *Pre-store shortest path between from any vertex u to v. It should take at most O(n^2) I think*. Now all the queries can be answered in O(1).

Comment: @AKSingh That would make the total time `O(N^2 + Q)` which is not substantially better than `O(Q*N)`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, If we use binary lifting here, maybe we can get to the solution in ```O(Q * (logN ^ 2))```. Not sure if binary lifting would be an overkill for it.

Comment: @tusharRawat Yes, that's what I've been thinking.  I think that would be `O(N log N)` to build it and then `O(Q log N)` to answer the queries.  So total `O((N+Q) log N)`

Comment: Further, you can use memoization to bound Q to N making a worst case of `O((N log N) + Q)`.

Comment: I am finding this problem very interesting, I might try to code something up (it'll take me at least a day though).

Comment: I suggest you share some link to the problem as well. Without any place to test the solution, it is not easy to decide which option is the preferred option.

Comment: @AKSingh, I'll add my solution using binary lifting. Problem is not available anymore, so you cannot access it now, though I can provide some 4-5 sample test cases, if you want.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Added a solution using binary lifting, Time Complexity : O(Q * log(n))

Comment: @tusharRawat It says that building the ancestor matrix is also `O(N log N)`, so total would be `O((N+Q) log N)`, yes?   Do you know if that's average or worst-case.  I found a few ways to get average `O((N+Q) log N)`, but there's a lot of pathological shapes so getting worst case down to that is proving challenging, but I think that I might have a method.

Comment: In fact, I am pretty sure that I can get `O(N + Q)` for *average* time complexity.  And for either *random* structures or *random* query sets, it should almost always achieve that.  However, for certain pathological structures combined with non-random query sets (always matching, but at maximum distances) I am not quite there yet.

Comment: Well, I have an answer that appears to be `O((N log N) + Q)`.  I will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find all the terminal cycles and designate an arbitrary vertex in each terminal cycle as the cycle root (O(N))
2. For each vertex, record the length of its terminal cycle, its distance to entry into the terminal cycle, and the distance to the terminal cycle root (O(N)).
3. Sever the outgoing link from each cycle root.  This turns the graph into a forest.
4. For each query, find the closest (lowest) common ancestor of the two query nodes in this forest.
5. From the information saved about each query node and the lowest common ancestor, you can figure out the time to collision in constant time.

Step (4), the lowest common ancestor query, is a very [well-studied problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor).  The best algorithms require only linear processing time and provide constant query time, leading to O(N + Q) time for this problem all together.

Comment: I have been preparing an answer that has a lot of similarity to this.  However, by severing the cycle-root's outlink (step 3), you actually change some of the query-answers.  I think that this can still work though, because when I classified all of the possible ways that a collision could occur, any collision on a cycle could be determined in effectively O(1).

Comment: Yes.  That's why you need the distance-to-cycle and cycle length in addition to the distanct-to-cycle-root

Comment: I've been reading the Wikipedia article on LCA and the related [Heavy-Path Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_path_decomposition) article, but it doesn't seem like they have enough information there to implement any of the O(n) algorithms.  They also imply that some of them are "more difficult to implement" which seems ominous.  any suggestions on a description that could be implemented?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Since you don't have to process queries in the given order, you can use Tarjan's LCA, which is simple and fast: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm  For in-order processing, I would use the reduction to range-minimum-query via Euler tour described here: http://www-di.inf.puc-rio.br/~laber/lca-rmq.pdf  That one is a lot of code, though.

Comment: Huh, I missed that link in the LCA article (possibly because I didn't catch the meaning of on/off-line).  I'll take a look at it... thanks for the link.

Comment: Ugh, the wiki article doesn't specify whether it's Tarjan's 79 version (super-linear) or the 83 version (linear) that is described in the pseudocode and the 83 source article is behind a paywall.  Worse,  a Talk comment claims that the pseudocode was actually lifted from CRLS (Cormen, et.al. 1990), was incorrectly attributed there, and is actually Aho, et.al.'s algorithm.  Man, Wikipedia sure can be frustrating sometimes.  I have found so many inaccurate reproductions of algorithms in there, it's crazy.

Comment: It's the super-linear version, but that's effectively linear.  The linear version is the same algorithm, but with optimizations to union-find described here: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82125836.pdf  In real life, that optimization is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out that I do have access to that paywall (ACM membership).  ... Yeah, the `Find(..)` didn't look linear to me.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the following approach *technically* achieves `O(N+Q)` time complexity.

### Observations

**Subgraphs**: The graph is not necessarily contiguous.  All graphs consist or one or more disjoint contiguous complete subgraphs, meaning:

- No nodes are shared between subgraphs ("disjoint")
- All of the nodes in the subgraph are connected ("contiguous")
- There are no paths connecting different subgraphs ("complete")

I will hereafter refer to these as the subgraphs of the graph or just "subgraphs".  These subgraphs have the following additional properties, which are a consequence of their definition (above) and the types of nodes in the graph (they are all "parent-pointer nodes" with exactly one out-edge/pointer):

- All such subgraphs must have exactly one cycle in them (because a cycle is the only way that they can terminate or be closed)
- The cycle can be of any length `cycle.Len >= 1`
- Additionally, there may be any number (`t >= 0`) trees attached to the cycle at their root (base)
- All nodes are either in the cycle or in one of these trees (the roots of the trees are in the cycle, but also counted as part of a tree)

**Terms:**

- **cycle Length**: The number of nodes in a cycle.
- **cycle Base**: An arbitrarily chosen node in the cycle used to measure and distances between two nodes in the same cycle, and also any two nodes in the same subgraph.
- **tree Base**: The base or root node of one of the trees attached to the cycle.  As the tree base is also the node that attaches it to the cycle, tree base nodes are counted as being in the cycle (and also part of their tree).
- **Distance**: For a node in the cycle, this is the distance (number of hops) from that node to the cycle Base (zero if it *is* the cycle Base).  For a node in a tree (not counting tree Base nodes, which count as in the cycle), this is the distance from that node to the tree Base node.

### Collisions Cases

#### Trivial

There are many ways or "forms" of collisions possible in a graph, but we can identify two trivial cases upfront:

| (A, B) Relation | Collide? | Collision Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| same node | Yes | 0 |
| different subgraphs | No | -1 |

Obviously, if A and B are the same node, then they trivially collide at distance zero.  Likewise, if they are in two different subgraphs, then they can never collide because there are no connections between the subgraphs.  For the collision cases that follow I will be assuming that these two cases have already been filtered out so that:

1. A and B are assumed to be different nodes, and
2. A and B are assumed to be in the same subgraph

#### Non-Trivial

The following table covers all of the other, non-trivial, cases of the relation between two nodes.

| (A, B) Relation | Collide? | Collision Distance | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| same cycle | No | -1 | nodes in cycle always stay the same distance apart |
| A in a tree & B in the cycle (or vice-versa) | if they both arrive at A's treeBase at the same time | -1 OR A.treeDist | if B.cycleDist = (A.treeDist MOD cycle.Len) |
| A and B are in different trees | if A and B's distance to their cycle.Base is equal MOD cycle.Len | MAX(A.treeDist, B.treeDist) | They meet when the farther one gets to the cycle (tree root) |
| A & B are in the same tree, but have different treeDist's | If their treeDist's are equal MOD cycle.Len | MAX(A.treeDist, B.treeDist) | They meet when the farther one gets to the cycle (tree root/base) |
| A & B are in the same tree, and have the same treeDist's | Yes | At their lowest common ancestor (LCA) in the tree | Have to search up the tree |

One important principle applied several times above is that *two different nodes in a cycle can never collide*.  This is because when each node follows its path around the cycle, they will always stay the same distance apart, there is no way for one node's path to "catch-up" to another's in the cycle.  They can only "collide" *if they start out in the cycle at the same node*.

The consequences of this are that:

1. Two different nodes in the cycle can never collide.
2. A node in a tree can only collide with a node in a cycle, if their total distances to the cycle base are the same Modulo the cycle length (that is the remainder when divided by the cycle length).
3. This is also true for two nodes in different trees and two nodes in the same tree but with different distances to their tree base.
4. In all of these cases (from #2 and #3), they will collide when the node that is farthest from its tree Base gets to the cycle (which is also its tree base). This is because nodes in the cycle cannot "catch-up" to each other, so they must always be the same once they are both in the cycle.  Thus they always collide when the farther one finally gets to the cycle.

Another important consequence is that every case in both tables above, except for the last one, can be answered in `O(1)` time, simply by annotating the nodes with so easily determined information:

1. their Base node (tree or cycle)
2. their Distance to that base node
3. the Subgraph they belong to
4. the Length of their subgraph's Cycle

These can all be easily determined when initializing the graph in `O(1)` time per node (or `O(N)` total time).

### Approach

#### Nodes

After the nodes are initially loaded into the graph (MPDGraph object), then I annotate the nodes with the additional information listed above.  This process (called "Mapping" in the code) proceeds as follows:

1. Pick any node
2. Follow it's path until it "terminates" by reaching a node already in it's path, or a node that was previously mapped
3. If #2 crossed it's own path, then we've found a new cycle. Designate the node we crossed as the base node of the cycle, and fill-in the mapping properties (cycle, base node, distance, etc.).  Unwind our path one node at a time, filling in each node and marking it as InCycle as we go back up the path until we reach the base node again.  Now we are ate the base of the tree that our path followed into the cycle, so when we move back to the pervious node in the path we switch to marking it as a tree node, until we return to the first node in our path.
4. If instead, #2 reached an already mapped node, then we well attach our path to that node and copy its tree/cycle, base etc. information to our current node.  Then we will return back up our path as in #3, setting the mapping properties of each node as we go,
5. If there are any unmapped nodes, pick one and goto #2.

This all takes `O(N)` time.

#### Queries

We have a method (called MPDGraph.FindCollision) that given two nodes will apply the rules in the two Collision Cases tables above and return the result.  For very case except the last (nodes in same tree and same distance) the distance can be determined in `O(1)` time by using the mapping properties.

If the two nodes are in the same tree and are also the same distance from their tree base, then they could meet anywhere between them and their common treeBase node.  For this case the `FindCollision(A,B)` method calls the `findTreeDistance(A,B)` which:

1. Returns zero if they are the same node.
2. Otherwise it checks a cache of previously calculated distances to see if  it has already been calculated for these two node.  If so, then it returns that value.
3. Otherwise, it calls `findTreeDistance` passing in the parents of the current two nodes to get their distance, and adds one to that.  Then it adds this to the cache and returns the value.

Without this memoization (i.e., the cache) this would take on average apprx. `O(log N)` for each query of this type. With the memoization it is hard to calculate but I would guess no worse than `O(log log N)` but for Q counts much larger than N, this will converge to `O(1)`.

This makes the query processing time complexity somewhere between `O(Q log log N)` and `O(Q)`, and the total time between `O(N + Q(log log N))` and `O(N + Q)`.

### Code

```
public static int[] collisionTime(int N, int Q, int[] A, int[,] queries)
{
    // create the graph and fill-in the mapping attributes for all nodes
    var graph = new MPDGraph(A);
    graph.MapAllNodes();

    int[] answers = new int[queries.GetLength(0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++)
    {
        answers[i] = graph.FindCollision(queries[i, 0], queries[i, 1]);
    }

    return answers;
}
```

This utilizes the following classes,

**MPDGraph Class:**

```
// MPDG: Mono-Pointing, Directed Graph 
//  An MPDG is a directed graph where every node has exactly one out-edge.
//  (MPDG is my own term, I don't know the real name for these)
class MPDGraph
{
    public Node[] Nodes;
    Dictionary<(Node, Node), int> cachedDistances = new Dictionary<(Node, Node), int>();

    // constructor
    public MPDGraph(int[] Pointers)
    {
        Nodes = new Node[Pointers.Length];

        // first fill the array with objects
        for (int i = 0; i < Nodes.Length; i++) { Nodes[i] = new Node(i); }

        // apply their pointers
        for(int i = 0; i < Nodes.Length; i++) { Nodes[i].toNode = Nodes[Pointers[i]]; }
    }


    // map all of the nodes by filling their mapping properties
    public void MapAllNodes()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<Nodes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!Nodes[i].isMapped)
                MapPath(Nodes[i], 1);
        }
    }

    // recursively map a path of unmapped nodes, starting from curr
    //  returns true if curr is in a cycle, false otherwise
    public Boolean MapPath(Node curr, int pathNo)
    {
        Boolean inCycle = false;
        curr.pathNo = pathNo;

        Node next = curr.toNode;

        if (next.IsInPath)
        {
            // we have found a new cycle
            Cycle Cycle = new Cycle(this, next, curr.pathNo - next.pathNo + 1);
            curr.Map(Cycle);
            return true;
        }
        else if (next.isMapped)
        {
            // we are joining an already partially mapped tree
            if (next.IsInCycle)
            {
                // next is a tree-Base, the top of our tree and also in the cycle
                curr.Map(next.Cycle, false, next, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                // next is a normal tree-node
                curr.Map(next.Cycle, false, next.BaseNode, next.Distance + 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // continue forward on the path, recurse to the next node
            inCycle = MapPath(next, pathNo+1);

            if (inCycle)
            {
                if (next.Cycle.Base == next || next.Distance == 0)
                {
                    //we have returned from the cycleBase, which is also a treeBase
                    // so, switch from Cycle to Tree
                    curr.Map(next.Cycle, false, next, 1);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // still in the cycle
                    curr.Map(next.Cycle);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //returned in tree
                curr.Map(next.Cycle, false, next.BaseNode, next.Distance + 1);
            }

            return inCycle;
        }

    }


    // Given two starting nodes, determine how many steps it takes until their
    //  paths collide. Returns -1 if they will never collide.
    public int FindCollision(int index1, int index2)
    {
        Node node1 = Nodes[index1];
        Node node2 = Nodes[index2];

        // eliminate trivial cases
        if (node1.Cycle != node2.Cycle)
            return -1;      // cant collide if they're in different subgraphs
        else if (node1 == node2)
            return 0;       // if they're the same node, then distance = 0
        else if (node1.IsInCycle && node2.IsInCycle)
            return -1;      // different nodes in a cycle never collide
        
        else
        {  // they're both in the same subgraph, use math to tell if they collide

            // get their distances to the cycle base
            int dist1 = node1.Distance + (node1.IsInCycle ? 0 : node1.BaseNode.Distance);
            int dist2 = node2.Distance + (node2.IsInCycle ? 0 : node2.BaseNode.Distance);
            int cycleLen = node1.Cycle.Length;

            // use math:  modulo(cycle length)
            if ((dist1 % cycleLen) != (dist2 % cycleLen))
            {
                return -1;      // incompatible distances: cannot possibly collide
            }
            else
            {
                // they must collide somewhere, figure out how far that is
                if (node1.IsInCycle || node2.IsInCycle)
                {
                    // if one is in the cycle, they will collide when
                    // the other one reaches the cycle (it's treeBase)
                    return (!node1.IsInCycle ? node1.Distance : node2.Distance);
                }
                else if (node1.BaseNode != node2.BaseNode)
                {
                    // They are in different trees:  they will collide at
                    //  the treeBase of the node that is farther
                    return Math.Max(node1.Distance, node2.Distance);
                }
                else
                {
                    // They are in the same tree:
                    if (node1.Distance != node2.Distance)
                    {
                        //if they are in the same tree, but have different distances
                        //  to the treeBase, then they will collide at the treeBase
                        //  when the farther one arrives at the treeBase
                        return Math.Max(node1.Distance, node2.Distance);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //  the hard case, have to walk down their paths
                        //  to find their LCA (Lowest Common Ancestor)
                        return findTreeDistance(node1, node2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    int findTreeDistance(Node node1, Node node2)
    {
        if (node1 == node2) return 0;

        // normalize their order
        if (node1.index > node2.index)
        {
            var tmp = node1;
            node1 = node2;
            node2 = tmp;
        }

        // check the cache
        int dist;
        if (cachedDistances.ContainsKey((node1,node2)))
        {
            dist = cachedDistances[(node1, node2)];
        }
        else
        {
            // keep recursing to find where they meet
            dist = findTreeDistance(node1.toNode, node2.toNode) + 1;
            // cache this new distance
            cachedDistances.Add((node1, node2), dist);
        }
        return dist;
    }
}
```

**Node Class:**

```
// Represents a node in the MPDG (Mono-Pointing Directed Graph) with the constraint
//  that all nodes have exactly one out-edge ("toNode").
class Node
{
    // Primary properties (from input)
    public int index { get; set; }      // this node's unique index (to the original array)
    public Node toNode { get; set; }    // what our single out-edge is pointing to


    public Node(int Index_) { this.index = Index_; }


    // Mapping properties
    // (these must be filled-in to finish mapping the node)

    //  The unique cycle of this node's subgraph (all MPDG-subgraphs have exactly one)
    public Cycle Cycle;

    //  Every node is either in their subgraphs cycle or in one of the inverted
    // trees whose apex (base) is attached to it.  Only valid when BaseNode is set.
    // (tree base nodes are counted as being in the cycle)
    public Boolean IsInCycle = false;

    // The base node of the tree or cycle that this node is in.
    //  If (IsInCycle) then it points to this cycle's base node (cycleBase)
    //  Else it points to base node of this node's tree (treeBase)
    public Node BaseNode;

    //  The distance (hops) from this node to the BaseNode
    public int Distance = -1;    // -1 if not yet mapped

    // Total distance from this node to the cycleBase
    public int TotalDistance { get { return Distance + (IsInCycle ? 0 : BaseNode.Distance); } }


    // housekeeping for mapping nodes
    public int pathNo = -1;          // order in our working path

    // Derived (implicit) properties
    public Boolean isMapped { get { return Cycle != null; } }
    public Boolean IsInPath { get { return (pathNo >= 0); } }


    public void Map(Cycle Cycle, bool InCycle = true, Node BaseNode = null, int distance_ = -1)
    {
        this.Cycle = Cycle; 
        IsInCycle = InCycle;

        if (InCycle)
        {
            this.BaseNode = Cycle.Base;
            Distance = (Cycle.Length + (Cycle.Base.pathNo - pathNo)) % Cycle.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BaseNode = BaseNode;
            Distance = distance_;
        }

        pathNo = -1;    // clean-up the path once we're done
    }
}
```

**Cycle Class:**

```
// represents the cycle of a unique MPDG-subgraph
//  (should have one of these for each subgraph)
class Cycle
{
    public MPDGraph Graph; // the MPDG that contains this cycle
    public Node Base;      // the base node of a subgraph's cycle
    public int Length;     // the length of this cycle

    public Cycle(MPDGraph graph_, Node base_, int length_)
    {
        Graph = graph_;
        Base = base_;
        Length = length_;
    }
}
```

#### Performance Measurements:

| Node Count | Build & Map Graph mean microsecs | Question Count | All Questions mean microsecs | Question mean microseconds | Total mean microseconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 0.9 | 1225 | 26 | 0.0212 | 26.9 |
| 500 | 10.1 | 124750 | 2267 | 0.0182 | 2277.1 |
| 1000 | 23.4 | 499500 | 8720 | 0.0175 | 8743.4 |
| 5000 | 159.6 | 12497500 | 229000 | 0.0183 | 229159.6 |
| 10000 | 345.3 | 49995000 | 793212 | 0.0159 | 793557.3 |

Comment: I don't think it's too hard to find an O(QN) case -- two long paths to a merge point, followed by a path to the terminal cycle.  Query the initial node of the first long path against every node of the second long path.  Every check to the distance cache will have a unique key.  You need to use a good LCA algorithm if you want O(N+Q)

Comment: @MattTimmermans It memoizes the paths of matching pairs while it is searching for collision points.  This is provably `O(N+Q)`  because as Q approaches infinity, it’s incremental complexity for each Q approaches O(1).   That’s why the single question times actually *go down* for larger N and Q, even though the average paths should be longer.

Comment: I have tried several pathological cases on it, and no matter what, it approaches O(N+Q) as Q gets large.  This is why I say that it’s *technically*  O(N+Q).  Though I do agree, using the LCA algorithm would be better.

Comment: OTOH, with the decision tree I am using, something like 2/3rds of random queries for a random graph can be answered in O(1) without the memoization.

Comment: *Technically*, O(N+Q) means O(N) if Q == N, but this is O(N^2) if Q = N, because that's how many distinct cache keys there are.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  Do you have a reference for that?  Because in this case N and Q are both subdivisions of the total `n` in the formal `O(n)` definition.  That is `n = N + Q`.  I've never seen formal descriptions of big-O for cases like that.  The usual odd cases are things like `O(m)` or `O(n+m)` where `m` is the magnitude of one of the parameters, and you have to convert to bit-complexity (i.e., `n = log m`), but not a case like this.

Comment: And even if I held `N == Q` it wouldn't be `O(N^2)`, it would be `O(N log log N)` at worst, and I cannot find a case that demonstrates that behavior.  The worst-case shapes I can come up with are what I call "feather-forks" which have two long prongs, as in your example (a "tuning fork") but each node of the prongs has an additional one-node path that connects to it.  Even here, with the path-memoization, it quickly reduces to `O(1)` per query.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  OK, I've been re-running my tests, and random trees and queries for `N=Q` do seem to demonstrate something like `O(n log log n)`.  I might try binary trees as a possible worst case for my algorithm.

Comment: I didn't consider your decision tree correctly.  It looks to me like the worst case here is m separate paths of length m, all in the same tree, with queries to all pairs of leaves (all same dist).  In this case N+Q = Ө(m^2), but time is Ө(m^3), so Ө(n^1.5) time in terms of the input size.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  Wow, nice example and analysis.  Seems correct to me.

Comment: And thanks for reading through the whole decision tree, I was really surprised at how many different query cases I could reduce to just math in O(1).  Now, if I can just figure out Tarzan’s LCA algorithm, I can get @@all of the cases down to O(1)…

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible for a collision to occur on a node that has more than 1 link leading to it.  Node D in your example.

Let's call these nodes "crash sites"

So you can prune your graph down to just the crash site nodes.  The nodes that lead to the crash site nodes become attributes of the crash site nodes.

Like this for your example:

```
D : { A,B,C }, { E,F,K }
```

A collision can ONLY occur if the starting nodes are on two different attribute lists of the same crash site node.

Once you are sure a crash can occurr, then you can check that both starting nodes are the same distance from the crash site.

Algorithm:

```
Prune graph to crash site nodes
LOOP over questions
Get 2 start nodes
LOOP over crash sites
   IF start nodes on two different attributes of crash site
        IF start nodes are equi-distant from crash site
             report crash time
             BREAK from crash site loop
```

Here is a randomly generated graph with 50 nodes where every node has one out edge connected to another node chosen randomly

[image]

The collision sites are

```
5 7 8 9 10 11 18 19 23 25 31 33 36 37 39
```

So the algorithm need only loop over 15 nodes, at most, instead of 50.

The answer to the question 'do two particular nodes collide?' is almost always 'NO'.  It is kind of boring that way.  So let's ask a slightly different question: 'for a particular graph, which pairs of nodes result in a collision?'  This requires the same algorithm ( applied to every pair of nodes ) but alway produces an interesting answer.

for this graph

[image]

I get this answer

```
0 and 29 collide at 41
1 and 5 collide at 40
2 and 23 collide at 13
8 and 16 collide at 34
8 and 22 collide at 34
8 and 39 collide at 34
9 and 30 collide at 37
10 and 31 collide at 25
11 and 47 collide at 23
12 and 28 collide at 25
12 and 35 collide at 25
12 and 49 collide at 25
13 and 38 collide at 27
14 and 44 collide at 1
15 and 17 collide at 0
15 and 18 collide at 0
15 and 37 collide at 0
16 and 22 collide at 34
16 and 39 collide at 34
17 and 18 collide at 0
17 and 37 collide at 0
18 and 37 collide at 0
20 and 26 collide at 9
20 and 42 collide at 9
20 and 43 collide at 9
21 and 45 collide at 24
22 and 39 collide at 34
25 and 34 collide at 3
26 and 42 collide at 9
26 and 43 collide at 9
28 and 35 collide at 25
28 and 49 collide at 25
32 and 48 collide at 34
33 and 36 collide at 7
35 and 49 collide at 25
42 and 43 collide at 9
```

Some timing results

| Node Count | Crash Sites millisecs | Question Count | Question mean microsecs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 0.4 | 1225 | 0.02 |
| 500 | 50 | 124750 | 0.02 |
| 5000 | 5500 | ~12M | 0.02 |
| 10000 | 30000 | ~50M | 0.03 |
| 30000 | 181000 | ~450M | 0.6 |

Notes:

- The mean time for a question is the average of checking every possible pair of nodes for a possible collision.
- Answering a single question is extremely fast, about 20 nanoseconds for moderately sized graphs ( < 10,000 nodes )  [ A previous timing report included outputting the results when a collision was found, which takes much longer than detecting the collision.  These results were taken with all output to the console commented out. ]
- Setting up the crash sites and their tributaries gets slow with moderately sized graphs ( > 5,000 nodes ).  It is only worth doing if a lot of questions are going to be asked.

The code for this is available at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder

Comment: So, if I read your timing results correctly, your questions list actually included every possible distinct question, is that correct?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes.

Comment: OP's "binary lifting" technique is faster in the worst case.

Comment: Also, if the crash site is on a terminal cycle, then two nodes can collide even if their distances are different, as long as the difference is a multiple of the cycle length.

Comment: Perhaps.  However the worst case is extremely rare.  So the question is, how fast is your method for routine cases.  I have seen no timing reports for any other approach to answering this question.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how long your method takes on a typical graph.  For the worst case, if you post an example of a worst case graph with a moderate node count ( say 5,000 nodes ) I will run a timing test on it.

Comment: Not *my* method -- I was talking about the (really quite good) method that the OP provided in the question.  He provided code, so you could time it. I've added an answer with my own method, though, which unfortunately takes way more work to implement than I would want to spend on it.

Comment: I would think that an algorithm that is too much trouble to implement is therefore of no use.  Simplicity is an important virtue for a useful algorithm